# How to add curvature to the background of a button in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-playground

```
        @IBAction func answerButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let userAnswer = sender.currentTitle!
        let userGotItRight = quizBrain.checkAnswer(userAnswer)
        
        if userGotItRight {
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        }else{
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        
        quizBrain.nextQuestion()
        
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: #selector(updateUI), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
    
    @objc func updateUI() {
        questionLabel.text = quizBrain.getQuestionText()

        buttonOne.setTitle(quizBrain.getTitle1(), for: .normal)
        buttonTwo.setTitle(quizBrain.getTitle2(), for: .normal)
        buttonThree.setTitle(quizBrain.getTitle3(), for: .normal)

        progressBar.progress = quizBrain.getProgress()

        scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(quizBrain.getScore())"

        self.buttonOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.buttonTwo.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.buttonThree.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        
    }
```

When the button is clicked, the background color is changed with sharp corners. I need the corners to be curved.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxh4K.png

Comment: button.layer.cornerRadius

Comment: You are the one who is saying `sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.green`. But that is not what you want, so don't say it. Set the background image to a green rounded rectangle.

Comment: @matt so I can add another image to the assets and change the border color? Background cannot be curved? right?

Comment: Personally I would just create the desired background image in real time.